# how can I add if statement?

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private sub complete_Click()

Docmd.RunSQL("Update Upload_Report set Status = '" & Completed & "' where Analyst = '" & Environ(Username) & "'")

Msgbox " Records are updated" , vbInformation
End sub
```

If the status in a Upload_Report table is already showing as completed then msgbox should indicate 'No records to get updated'.

Can someone please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Search the table before executing UPDATE (can use DCount or DLookup) and use that result to determine if UPDATE should run and provide appropriate message.

Comment: What is value of `Completed` variable - true or false? Do you want to update ALL of the specified analysts records? Or should there be some additional criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this (using `Execute` and not `RunSQL`)

```vb
Dim db as Database
Dim SQL

Set db = CurrentDb()

SQL = "update Upload_Report set Status = '" & Completed & _
      "' where status <> '" & Completed  & _
      "' and Analyst = '" & Environ(Username) & "'"

db.Execute SQL

MsgBox db.RecordsAffected & " records updated"
```